# Understanding Dynamic Frequency Warping (not Dynamic Time Warping)

Tags: algorithms, signal-processing

I am implementing a paper which need Dynamic Frequency Warping as a component. They have written very briefly about this algorithm and cite to 
[this paper: Voice transformation using PSOLA technique](http://kom.aau.dk/project/sipcom/SIPCom05/sites/sipcom8/courses/SIPCom8-4/mm8/valbret_moulines_tubach.pdf) (page 9/13 of the PDF, section 3.3). I have read it but can't understand its mechanic. I've also made some search on Google but almost have no improvement. As I understand, DFW take an input of 2 spectra (A and B) and then calculate a warping matrix that convert A->B. Can someone give me some clearer intuition?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This sounds better suited to [electronics.se].